# How to put text before and after a button in BootstrapCSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I using Bootstrap and trying to place some text at the same line with a button. I need some words to be shown just before the button and some other after.
This is what I have:

```
<div class="input-group">
    Match
    <div class="input-group-btn" id="drop_operator_list">
       <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">
         <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dropdown-toggle" id="modal-button-and-or" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">
               <span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-and-or" id="and-or" style="height: auto; max-height: 200px; overflow-x: hidden;">
                   <li><a href="#" id="AND">AND</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#" id="OR">OR</a></li>
                 </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          Everything
        </div>
```

Although the above puts everything in the same row, it adds whitespaces before and after the strings and shows them as in the attachment:
[image]

Comment: Have you considered using the `content` property of `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements?

Comment: Thanks. This would mean I have to add rules in my CSS. I was wondering if there is a non-CSS solution.

Comment: What would a *"non-CSS"* solution look like? Are you suggesting an HTML solution?  Also, why tag CSS if you don't want a CSS solution?

Comment: I meant I would prefer not to change/add rules on my current CSS file. Perhaps there is a CSS class of bootstrap, which I am not aware of and could deal with this kind of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to achieve it with adding just one more set of `div` tags and moving the words outside of the input group.  And a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/GblXlVUNMy).

```
<div class="form-inline">
    Match
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-btn" id="drop_operator_list">
           <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">
             <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dropdown-toggle" id="modal-button-and-or" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">
                   <span class="caret"></span></button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-and-or" id="and-or" style="height: auto; max-height: 200px; overflow-x: hidden;">
                       <li><a href="#" id="AND">AND</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#" id="OR">OR</a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
         </div> 
     Everything
    </div>
```

As suggested, adding this CSS will counteract the breaking at 768px of `.form-inline`.

```
.form-inline .input-group {
    display: inline-table; vertical-align: middle; 
 } 

.form-inline .input-group .input-group-btn {
    width: auto; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But this actually doesn't work as it doesn't put them inline but above and under the button.

Comment: @dkar Um. Did you look at the Bootply?  It works fine within those confines.  If it's not working for you then either you're not using `.form-inline` or other things within your project are affecting it.

Comment: Bootstrap looks different when the screen width is less than 768px

Comment: Add part of bootstrap.css to your solution: `.form-inline .input-group {
  display: inline-table;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.form-inline .input-group .input-group-btn {
  width: auto;
}`

Comment: @GlebKemarsky It is correct that this will still break to new lines when smaller than 768px.  Your CSS fix seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set some attributes for `.input-group` and `.input-group-btn`:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.input-group {
  display: inline-table;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.input-group .input-group-btn {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
  Match
  <div class="input-group-btn" id="drop_operator_list">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dropdown-toggle" id="modal-button-and-or" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-and-or" id="and-or" style="height: auto; max-height: 200px; overflow-x: hidden;">
          <li><a href="#" id="AND">AND</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" id="OR">OR</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  Everything
</div>
```